# The target-entity cannot be found in the same namespace

Tags: php, symfony, entity

Hi guys I've a strange fault.

I've two entities and they are in the same namespace, but they are not in the same folder:
- The Card entity is in AppBundle\Entity\Card folder
- The Minnie entity is in AppBundle\Entity\Card\Subfolder folder
When I use the Card entity, it says:

> The target-entity AppBundle\Entity\Card\Minnie cannot be found in 'AppBundle\Entity\Card\Card#minnies'.

I can't understand why. I've searched in this forum, and everyone says that if two classes are in the same namespace, it needs only the entity's name when I use a referrer to Minnie's entity. Why in this case it doesn't work?

Card Class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Card;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="card")
 */
class Card {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=55)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * Many Cards have Many Pippos.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Pippo", inversedBy="cards")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="pippo_jointable")
 */
private $pippos;

/**
 * Many Cards have Many Topolinos.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Topolino", inversedBy="cards")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="topolino_jointable")
 */
private $topolinos;

/**
 * Many Cards have Many Minnie.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Minnie", inversedBy="cards")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="minnie_jointable")
 */
private $minnies;

public function __construct() {
    $this->pippos= new ArrayCollection();
    $this->topolinos = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->minnies = new ArrayCollection();
}
}
```

Minnie's Class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Card;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="minnie")
 */
class Minnie {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=55)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * Many Minnie have Many Cards.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Card", mappedBy="minnies")
 */
private $cards;

public function __construct() {
    $this->cards = new ArrayCollection();
}
}
```

If it can help, this is the code that uses the Card entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;

use AppBundle\Entity\Card\Card;
use AppBundle\Form\CardType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/create-card", name="create-card")
     */
    public function adminCardMainPageAction(Request $request) {
        $card = new Card();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $form = $this->createForm(CardType::class, $card);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        return $this->render('/admin/card-creation.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: i can only see a class "Ability" - where is "Minnie" ? :)

Comment: Yeah sorry. Edited.

Comment: the namespace of the class must match the folder hierarchy you put the class file into, e.g. `namespace AppBundle\Entity\Card\Subfolder;`

Comment: Typically your entities would actually be in AppBundle\Entity.  Not down one level.  Under Symfony, Doctrine is defined with an alias to AppBundle\Entity by default.  So change all your target names to Card\Card and Card\Minnie or move the class files up one level.

Comment: @Cerad Great! It works, thank you!!